# Create one image in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to create an image with JavaScipt, the image appear on a button click. The problem is when the image is created and i click again the button another one appear, and i don't want that.

How i can solve that?

```js
var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('Table');

img.onload = function() {
  div.appendChild(img);
};

img.src = 'Images/Email.png';
```

Comment: check first if image exists or not. 
then  and only then append. 
Sample usage.
// The "callback" argument is called with either true or false
// depending on whether the image at "url" exists or not.
function imageExists(url, callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() { callback(true); };
  img.onerror = function() { callback(false); };
  img.src = url;
}

// Sample usage
var imageUrl = 'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png';
imageExists(imageUrl, function(exists) {
  console.log('RESULT: url=' + imageUrl + ', exists=' + exists);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a flag, which indicate when the image has been created, loaded and added to your DOM:

```js
 var div = document.getElementById('Table');
    var hasImage = false; // flag
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
       createImage();
    });
    var createImage = function(){
      if(!hasImage) {
          var img = new Image();
          img.src = 'http://pipsum.com/435x310.jpg';
          img.onload = function() {
            div.appendChild(img);
            hasImage = true;
          };
        }else{
            console.log('image is already present');
        }
    };
```

```html
    <button id="button" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="Table"></div >
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the image is already added to the DOM. If not, do so. If already added, only update the source.

It could be something like this:

```
var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('Table');
var appended = false;

function appendImage() {
    appended = true;
    div.appendChild(img);

    img.removeEventListener('load', appendImage);
}

function onClick() {
    if (!appended) {
        img.addEventListener('load', appendImage);
    }

    img.src = 'Images/Email.png';
}
```